# Android ANR by ServiceTimeout only in Samsung

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile, android-anr-dialog

I got an ANR exception in my app, I can find nothing in log, then I get the trace.txt file, What I can only find is "ServiceTimeOut"(no "held by" text int the file), I check my Services in my app carefully, I can sure that there are no time-consuming tasks in onCreate and onCommandStart methods (main thread). The most strange thing is that this problem only occurs in Samsung S6 Edge (API 22). I will be appreciative if someone can give me some explanations.

And this is the part of the trace.txt file :

```
DALVIK THREADS (63):
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x86e26000 self=0xf4c28000
  | sysTid=32675 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf7531bec
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=3763 stm=377 core=2 HZ=100
  | stack=0xff77c000-0xff77e000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/32675/stack)
  native: #00 pc 00013458  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+28)
  native: #01 pc 000b055f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::Wait(art::Thread*)+98)
  native: #02 pc 001db095  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::SetFloatArrayRegion(_JNIEnv*, _jfloatArray*, int, int, float const*)+976)
  native: #03 pc 000af20f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
  native: #04 pc 000128a9  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+484)
  native: #05 pc 00012951  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+92)
  native: #06 pc 00089f5d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
  native: #07 pc 000b75db  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+102)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

"ActivityManager" prio=5 tid=19 TimedWaiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x13136890 self=0x7fa54b3800
  | sysTid=3976 nice=-2 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7f98d1a400
  | state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=34913 stm=21676 core=0 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7f8e517000-0x7f8e519000 stackSize=1036KB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait!(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x3fb164aa> (a com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$7)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:422)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.dumpStackTraces(ActivityManagerService.java:7834)
  - locked <0x3fb164aa> (a com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$7)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.dumpStackTraces(ActivityManagerService.java:7811)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.appNotResponding(ActivityManagerService.java:8062)
  at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.serviceTimeout(ActiveServices.java:3016)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$MainHandler.handleMessage(ActivityManagerService.java:2366)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
  at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

Comment: Hello, did you solve it? I had similar ANR log

Comment: @BartoszKraszewski No, I haven't yet solved it and I have left the project, so I have no chance to concern this problem.